# Protobuf map unserialization issue

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization, protocol-buffers

Consider the following .proto definition:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "Test";

message Book
{
    string name = 1;
    map<string, PersonInfo> persons = 2;
}

message PersonInfo
{
    string name = 1;
    string details = 2;
}
```

I want to serialize to a file an instance of `Book` and later deserialize it:

```
 var book1 = new Book() { Name = "Book1" };
 book1.Persons.Add("Person1", new PersonInfo() { Name = "Person1", Details = "Some details" });

 //serialization
 var book1JsonStr = JsonSerializer.Serialize(book1);

 //unserialization
 var book2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Book>(book1JsonStr);
```

The object `book1` is populated correctly:

[image]

And the serialized string is also correct:

[image]

The issue arises when we unserialize the object back:

[image]

"Regular" fields (string, double, int) are unserialized, but the map (`Google.Protobuf.Collections.MapField<TKey, TValue>`) it is not. Why this is happening? Is this a bug?

What can I do to unserialize a `MapField`?

Comment: Which JsonSerializer is that? Is that the protobuf JSON API? Or something like Newtonsoft? The Google protobuf implementation includes (opinionated) JSON support, but honestly: most of the time, if you're working with protobuf schemas: you'll be using protobuf binary serialization, not JSON. If it *is* a 3rd party serialization library, then it is entirely possible that it omits some required API that your 3rd party serializer wants. The designers of a serialization tool expect you to use *that serialization*, not someone else's.

Comment: @MarcGravell I am using the serialization from `System.Text.Json`. The suprising fact is that the serialization is ok. The issue is reconstructing the object from the Json string. I am (was) reusing the classes generated by the protobuf compiler to store some cache in a file. Most surely this was not a good idea and it is better to use the proto generated classes for its original purpose: binary serialization for grpc.

Comment: protobuf works just fine outside of gRPC, too, for files etc - in fact, for several years protobuf was open source and well used but gRPC was closed inside google

Comment: @MarcGravell I followed your hint about the serialization library. Apparently `Newtonsoft.Json` works better than `System.Text.Json` for unserializing the `MapField`.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you found a solution, but that wasn't what I was suggesting. I was suggesting *use protobuf* :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Newtonsoft.Json` instead of `System.Text.Json` solved this issue.

```
 var book1 = new Book() { Name = "Book1" };
 book1.Persons.Add("Person1", new PersonInfo() { Name = "Person1", Details = "Some details" });

 //serialization
 var book1JsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(book1);

 //unserialization
 var book2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<Book>(book1JsonStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Protobuf.System.Text.Json` extension for `System.Text.Json` to fix your issue (which can be found as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Protobuf.System.Text.Json/)).

```
var book1 = new Book() { Name = "Book1" };
book1.Persons.Add("Person1", new PersonInfo() { Name = "Person1", Details = "Some details" });

//serialization
var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
jsonSerializerOptions.AddProtobufSupport();
var book1JsonStr = JsonSerializer.Serialize(book1, jsonSerializerOptions);

//deserialization
var book2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Book>(book1JsonStr, jsonSerializerOptions);
```